# Increase Speed of Python Function

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, coordinates

I have a region of interest.I wanted to apply the same python function "calculate" 100 * 100 = 10000 times.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pvlib.location import Location
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


longitude_extent = (50, 60)
latitude_extent = (110, 120)

longitudes = np.linspace(50, 60, 100)
latitudes = np.linspace(110, 120, 100)


date_time = "2022-07-01 00:00:00"

def calculate (lat, lon):
   site = Location(lat, lon, 'utc', 0)
   solar_position = site.get_solarposition(date_time)['zenith']
   return solar_position

result = np.zeros ((100, 100))
for ix, lon in enumerate(longitudes):
   for jx, lat in enumerate(latitudes):
        res = calculate(lat,lon)
        result[ix, jx] = res
```

However, it runs extremely slowly.
Any ideas to make it faster?

Comment: Are you wanting to make the function more efficient or parallelize or both?

Comment: @David I want both..

Comment: It looks like the code is broken in its current state. Edit the code to fix it and then we can edit it. It looks like your def is missing ":". Additionally, "ij" hasnt been initiated (perhaps it should be jx?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following achieves a ~5x speedup on my machine (2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9) over the presented solution using `ProcessPoolExecutor`. YMMV depending on the number of processors on your machine:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from itertools import product

import numpy as np
from pvlib.location import Location


longitude_extent = (50, 60)
latitude_extent = (110, 120)

longitudes = np.linspace(50, 60, 100)
latitudes = np.linspace(110, 120, 100)

date_time = "2022-07-01 00:00:00"


def calculate(pair):
    return Location(*pair).get_solarposition(date_time)['zenith']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        result = executor.map(calculate, product(latitudes, longitudes))

    print(list(result))
```

In general, when trying to speed up compute-heavy workloads in Python, you're going to want to use multiprocessing instead of multithreading because of the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock).